# Data in Firestore not updating

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is a `javascript` function intending to perform an update on `FireStore`, which does not work.

I will be more that happy if anyone can see an issue in the code.

```
function makeUpdate(key,name) {
    let theCollection = db.collection("InformationList"),
    infoUnit = theCollection.doc(key).get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("infoUnit -name-:" + doc.get("name"));
            console.log("infoUnit -telephone-:" + doc.get("telephone"));
            let updateDico = {};
            updateDico["name"] = name;
            doc.update(updateDico);
        } else {
            console.log("embassyUpdate --> No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error getting documents (in makeUpdate)", err);
    });
}
```

Apart from the fact that it does not perform the expected update, it prints three messages in the logs:

- infoUnit -name-: some name
- infoUnit -telephone-: some telephone number
- Error getting documents (in makeUpdate)

From that I can see that a record is found in the database as expected. But at the same time an unknown error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `update()` method on `doc` (which a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) object).  A DocumentSnapshot just contains the data read from `get()`.  If you want to write data back into a document, you'll need to use a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) object, probably the same one you got when you called `theCollection.doc(key)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method called `update()` which you can invoke on `doc` [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) object itself.

You'll have to use the `set()` method on the [Document Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) which you get from `doc.ref` to update the reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've updated my data.

```
     await db
      .collection('collectionName')
      .doc('documentId')
      .update({
        name: "Updated Name",
        telephone: "0000000000"
      });
```

You need to know document id and you can update your value like this.